# Buffer Overflow - Char Array not removed from stack after exiting function

Tags: c, string, strcat

I am trying to concatenate a few strings to a buffer. However, if I call the function repeatedly, the size of my buffer will keep growing.

```
void print_message(char *str) {
    char message[8196];
    sender *m = senderlist;
    while(m) {
        /* note: stricmp() is a case-insensitive version of strcmp() */
        if(stricmp(m->sender,str)==0) {
            strcat(message,m->sender);
            strcat(message,", ");
        }
        m = m->next;
    }
    printf("strlen: %i",strlen(message));
    printf("Message: %s\n",message);
    return;
}
```

The size of message will continuously grow until the length will be 3799.

Example:

- 1st. call: strlen = 211
- 2nd call: strlen = 514
- 3rd call: strlen = 844
- ...
- nth call: strlen = 3799
- nth +1 call: strlen = 3799
- nth +2 call: strlen = 3799

My understanding was, that statically allocated variables like char[] will automatically be freed upon exiting the function, and I'm not dynamically allocating anything on the heap.

And why will suddenly stop growing at 3799 bytes? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: How is message retaining its value between each function call ,its not static.And how did you get the example output?i think there is  something wrong with your question.

Comment: That is an indeterminate automatic variable. You cannot rely on it to be pre-initialized with a leading 0-char. The compiler generated code that happens to land that var on the same memory when that variable becomes active with the call-activation record of your invoke (which you conveniently left out). Declaring it as `char message[8196] = "";` will likely get you the behavior you intended.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Re-ininiatlizing message on every call did the trick. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more statement after the buffer definition

```
char message[8196];
message[0] = '\0';
```

Or initialize the buffer when it is defined

```
char message[8196] = { '\0' };
```

or

```
char message[8196] = "";
```

that is fully equivalent to the previous initialization.

The problem with your code is that the compiler does not initialize the buffer if you wiil not specify initialization explicitly. So array message contains some garbage but function `strcat` at first searches the terminating zero in the buffer that to append a new string. So your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to re-initalize the variable on every call,

char message[8196] = ""

did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the growing of the senderlist or likely garbage in message. Fortunately not exceeding 8196.
The message array must start with the empty string. At the moment doing a strcat adds to garbage.

```
char message[8196];
sender *m = senderlist;
int len = 0;
*message = '\0';
while(m) {
    /* note: stricmp() is a case-insensitive version of strcmp() */
    if(stricmp(m->sender,str)==0) {
        int sender_len = strlen(m->sender);
        if (len + sender_len + 2 + 1 < sizeof(message)) {
            strcpy(message + len, m->sender);
            len += sender_len;
            strcpy(message + len, ", ");
            len += 2;
        } else {
            // Maybe appending "..." instead (+ 3 + 1 < ...).
            break;
        }
    }
    m = m->next;
}
printf("strlen: %i",strlen(message));
printf("Message: %s\n",message);
```

Answer (score 1):

"Deallocation" is not the same as wiping the data; in fact, C generally leaves the data unerased for performance reasons.